# CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS treats every space as a delimiter for compiler flags and spaces are required within a single option

Tags: cmake

I am using cmake on a project and changing the value of CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS in a toolchain file, but the change is not doing what I intend. Here is the cmake toolchain file I am using to specify the compiler, add compiler flags, and add linker flags.

```
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Windows)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR AMD64)

set(compiler "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.27.29110/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe")
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER ${compiler})
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER ${compiler})

set(prgx86 "C:/Program Files (x86)")
set(winkit_include_root "${prgx86}/Windows Kits/10/Include/10.0.18326.0")

set(inc_a "/I/\"${prgx86}/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.27.29110/include\"")
set(inc_b "/I/\"${winkit_include_root}/um\"")
set(inc_c "/I/\"${winkit_include_root}/ucrt\"")
set(inc_d "/I/\"${winkit_include_root}/shared\"")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${inc_a} ${inc_b} ${inc_c} ${inc_d}")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${inc_a} ${inc_b} ${inc_c} ${inc_d}")


set(lib_a "/LIBPATH:\"${prgx86}/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.27.29110/lib/x64\"")
set(lib_b "/LIBPATH:\"${prgx86}/Windows Kits/10/Lib/10.0.18326/um/x64\"")
set(lib_c "/LIBPATH:\"${prgx86}/Windows Kits/10/Lib/10.0.18326/ucrt/x64\"")
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${lib_a} ${lib_b} ${lib_c}")
```

The problem here is the `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "...")` line. When I attempt to use this toolchain file, cmake fails to build the simple test program. This is the monstrosity I found in `CMakeError.log` after running cmake.

```
Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.27.29110/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe 
Build flags: /I/"C:/Program;Files;(x86)/Microsoft;Visual;Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.27.29110/include";/I/"C:/Program;Files;(x86)/Windows;Kits/10/Include/10.0.18326.0/um";/I/"C:/Program;Files;(x86)/Windows;Kits/10/Include/10.0.18326.0/ucrt";/I/"C:/Program;Files;(x86)/Windows;Kits/10/Include/10.0.18326.0/shared"
Id flags:  

The output was:
2
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.27.29111 for x64
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

cl : Command line warning D9024 : unrecognized source file type 'Files', object file assumed
cl : Command line warning D9024 : unrecognized source file type '(x86)/Microsoft', object file assumed
cl : Command line warning D9024 : unrecognized source file type 'Visual', object file assumed
cl : Command line warning D9024 : unrecognized source file type 'Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.27.29110/include"', object file assumed
cl : Command line warning D9024 : unrecognized source file type 'Files', object file assumed
cl : Command line warning D9024 : unrecognized source file type '(x86)/Windows', object file assumed
cl : Command line warning D9024 : unrecognized source file type 'Kits/10/Include/10.0.18326.0/um"', object file assumed
cl : Command line warning D9024 : unrecognized source file type 'Files', object file assumed
cl : Command line warning D9024 : unrecognized source file type '(x86)/Windows', object file assumed
cl : Command line warning D9024 : unrecognized source file type 'Kits/10/Include/10.0.18326.0/ucrt"', object file assumed
cl : Command line warning D9024 : unrecognized source file type 'Files', object file assumed
cl : Command line warning D9024 : unrecognized source file type '(x86)/Windows', object file assumed
cl : Command line warning D9024 : unrecognized source file type 'Kits/10/Include/10.0.18326.0/shared"', object file assumed
CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.27.29111.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

/out:Files.exe 
Files 
(x86)/Microsoft 
Visual 
Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.27.29110/include\ 
Files 
(x86)/Windows 
Kits/10/Include/10.0.18326.0/um\ 
Files 
(x86)/Windows 
Kits/10/Include/10.0.18326.0/ucrt\ 
Files 
(x86)/Windows 
Kits/10/Include/10.0.18326.0/shared\ 
CMakeCXXCompilerId.obj 
LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'Files.obj'


Detecting C compiler ABI info failed to compile with the following output:
Change Dir: C:/Users/underdisc/home/tech/varkor/build/msvc64/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
```

It seems pretty obvious that cmake is interpreting every space as a delimiter for different flags when they are actually a part of a single flag. I have tried escaping these spaces with backslashes and the results are the same. Is there a way to pass these flags to the compiler as intended? The version of cmake is 3.18.1.

#### Small Note

This is unrelated to the question, but very related to what I am doing in case anyone is curious about what they are looking at. I am trying to build my project from within my mintty-tmux terminal setup on windows. I want to avoid using the developer command prompt that ships with visual studio. I have tried using the `vcvars[32|64].bat` files in the past and again recently, but they have never worked. I think this has to do with the cygwin setup I have, but I have never known exactly why. I only use a limited set of things from cygwin too. For example, I am using a native windows build of cmake, not the one shipped with cygwin.

Comment: Try like `set(prgx86 "C:/Program\\ Files\\ (x86)")`.

Comment: I gave that a try and it seems like cmake gets by the compiling step of the test program, but it still breaks on the link step. The compile flags still contain semicolons instead of spaces, but they seem to be accepted as one argument. `Build flags: /I"C:/Program\;Files\;(x86)...` This is fine for the cmake compiler test, but I don't think this will work when compiling a file that actually includes some generic header file.

Comment: Have you tried `set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "${compiler}")` (with `"` around `${compiler}`)?

Comment: No, I hadn't tried that. CMake is not having any issues finding the compiler. The path I give it works without any problems. The issue is the that if a flag is given to the compiler and that single flag has spaces in it, cmake splits up that single flag into multiple smaller flags. So `/I"C:/Program Files (x86)/"` gets passed to the compiler as 3 parameters. `/I"C:/Program`, `Files`, and `(x86)/"`.

Comment: ran into this as well and filed an issue: https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/24385